# Pass data from RecyclerView Adapter to Parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-adapter

I have a screen with a EditText to find content and a RecyclerView.

The EditText is to find in my web server

The RecyclerView shows most popular tags used

So, What I want to do is, when the user click any of the elements of the RecyclerView List 
that value selected is passed to editText.

I have a fragment which inflate the file which show all the stuff:

**tags_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org............BuscarFragment">   
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:hint="@string/busqueda"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buscar_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etiquetas_populares"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buscar_msg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/etiquetas_populares"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/tags_list"
        android:name="org............TagsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etiquetas_populares"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context="org...........activities.TagsActivity"
        tools:listitem="@layout/tags_list_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In **TagsFragment.java** I have this method:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tags_list, container, false);

        //RecyclerView Section
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.tags_list);
        mBuscarTagsAdapter = new BuscarTagsAdapter(getActivity(), tagMoreUsedRecyclerViewList);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mBuscarTagsAdapter);


        addKeyListener();
        return view;
    }
```

Finally in my Adapter.

BuscarTagsAdapter.java

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BuscarTagsViewHolder holder, int position) {


        final int posicion = position;


        //onClick for the list
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //When the user click I want to pass this value to my EditText, but
                //I don't see how to do it from this Adapter

                Toast.makeText(context, tags.get(posicion).getTagName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea?
Thanks

**UPDATED and SOLVED:**

Hi, @Brian Nam, thanks for help.

Made some changes.
First in Constructor as you suggested:

```
    public BuscarTagsAdapter(Context context, List<TagMoreUsedRecyclerView> items, TagsListInterface tagsListInterface) {

            this.context = context;
            this.tags = items;
            this.tagsListInterface = tagsListInterface;

}
```

but tagsListInterface is not initialized properly in TagsFragment, 
so I added this in onCreate method:

```
 tagsListInterface = new TagsListInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onTagClicked(String tagName, int posicion) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                editText.setText(tagName);
            }
        };
```

Finally in onClick for the RecyclerView:

**BuscarTagsAdapter.java**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BuscarTagsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final int posicion = position;
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, tags.get(posicion).getTagName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tagsListInterface.onTagClicked(tags.get(posicion).getTagName(), posicion);


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can pass fragment to adapter and in adapter you can call method with a value which you want to pass from fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no "good" way to do this. I'd say instead of interfaces you should check out one of the event bus implementations like EventBus from Greenrobot.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

The good thing about using something like EventBus (basically the publisher-subscriber pattern) is that you spare a lot of anonym classes, interfaces but you also make the code less coupled. Not to mention any class can subscribe to the events so you can basically say "The user did this" and multiple fragments can react to it. This is especially useful if you do complex UI/animation stuff.

The bad thing about EventBus is that you start having a lot of events code quality suffers, and its sometimes hard to know what happens and where.

But as I said there's no "good" way to do this, thats just how the android framework works.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian Nam wrote, you can pass a reference to a `TagsFragment` instance to your `BuscarTagsAdapter`.

A similar but IMO a little bit more 'clean' solution would be to create an interface e.g.:

```
public interface TagsListInterface {
    void onTagClicked(String tagName);
}
```

Then your `TagsFragment` would implement the interface and pass an instance of it to `BuscarTagsAdapter`. Then you would call the `onTagClicked` method of that interface when an element of the Recycler View is clicked.

Another solution is to communicate the RecyclerView with your Fragment via your Activity which, as I believe, is the most 'Android-like' one. It could also involve creating a custom interface but it is the Activity that would implement it instead of a Fragment. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). The article explains how to perform a communication between  fragments but I believe it can show you the general idea so you can apply it to your situation.

**Update:**

In `onCreateView` method you are calling:

```
mBuscarTagsAdapter = new BuscarTagsAdapter(getActivity(), tagMoreUsedRecyclerViewList);
```

The only thing you have to change here is to update the constructor of `BuscarTagsAdapter` to receive an instance of `TagsListInterface` and then pass your implementation from `TagsFragment`. Then you are able to use it to call `onTagClicked` when an element is clicked.